# Map a movie within a HTML5 video tag to modal

Tags: html, css, dictionary, html5-video

I have a movie I'm playing on a site that I would like to map (like an image) so that I can have people click on a certain area of the movie tag so to speak.  I've basically done it how I used to image map way back in 2005, but it's not panning out.  Has anyone given this a try at all?

```
<div usemap="#myMap">
<video width="895" height="495" controls>
   <source src="someMovie.webm" type="video/webm" loop="loop">
</video>
<map name="myMap"> 
<area shape="rect" coords="some coordinates here" href="myAddress"> </aread>
</map>
```

My button just told me that the map tag has been deprecated.....so does anyone know how to do this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm far from an expert in this field, but you should be able to accomplish this by placing a `div` wrapped in an `<a>` tag in the parent div of the `<video>` tag and positioning it in front of the `<video>` element with CSS - something along the lines of "`position: absolute; z-index: 1; margin: {some_values};`".

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a8atS/2/